# Outlook Microsoft 365 add account error: An encrypted connection to your mail server is not available

Tags: outlook, azure-virtual-machine, microsoft365

I have been using Microsoft 365 Outlook since past year in Azure VM. Recently I reset the password of my Azure VM. Since then I am not able to access Outlook inside Azure VM.

I reinstalled Office 365 apps and tried to add account. But then I got error that:

> An encrypted connection to your mail server is not available. Click
> Next to attempt using an encrypted connection.

What can I do to resolve this error?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> An encrypted connection to your mail server is not available. Click
> Next to attempt using an encrypted connection.

To resolve this error, ***Go to outlook File -> add account -> click manual setup or additional server type button like below***

[image]

Select ***POP or IMAP*** -> next ->make changes ***user information, server information and logon information like below snip and click on More setting***

[image]

***In internet E-mail setting under outgoing server tab, please check my outgoing server option and in advanced tab please select -> ***TLS or SSL*** instead of none and SMTP should be 587 -> ok -> next Test account setting -> close and finish your information will be set up to the account as below***.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Imran! I tried the above settings. In my Internet Email Settings, I don't see TLS option for encrypted connection. There are SSL/TSL, STARTTLS and Auto options available. So I tried STARTTLS or SSL/TSL options, then I keep on getting password prompt, even if I saved the password and cancelling out of the prompt results in "Log onto incoming mail server (IMAP) failed". It sends  the outgoing test email without issue.

Comment: Please check this [Alternative](https://youtu.be/-p61q5qpGXk) way may solve your issue